# After changing product details the boost rule applied not working

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

Make a product hero product by clicking star from backoffice. It will show at top.Then go to administration view and change the details of that product i.e. identifier or summary of that product in staged version and then synchronized this . Then go to commerce search view and see the product that we made a hero product is not hero product now and it goes at the place where it was before making a hero product.

Can anybody have idea ?I think, It should be as hero product after editing any details of that product It should see at top after editing the product details.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to reindex solr by Updating Solr Index in your backoffice , you can do so by clicking on Hot Update Index button, you will find it :

```
Administration -> System -> facet Search -> Facet search config -> Hot Update Index
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a product a Hero product in Hybris is just adding an incredibly high boost score to the given product codes. As this is a query-time operation against SOLR, as opposed to an index-time operation, simply doing a re-index will not fix this problem.

From experience, the closest thing this sounds like is a caching issue. As both the Backoffice commerce search and the storefront share the same service code, if you've added a caching strategy such as EhCache, you may find that this is retaining the result set each time as it is skipping SOLR and getting results from the cache.

### Testing the Caching Scenario

You should be able to test this theory by doing the following:

- If you have caching, try to find the strategy used, and determine its eviction policy and time to live (ie. LFU, and 30 mins TTL)
- Go to the commerce search perspective in the Backoffice
- Pick a category
- Pick an product to make a hero product
- Temporarily this should promote it to the top of the page
- Change category once, then return to the previous category
- You should once again have replicated the issue, now double check on the storefront to see if the result set is the same
- Now wait for as long as the Time To Live of your caching. If you do not have a TTL, but instead have a Time To Idle, then you need to ensure nobody else accesses the same element from the cache
- Once the item has expired, go back to the Backoffice
- You will know that caching is the issue if your Hero product now displays in the correct place. You can also check once again on the storefront to see if your hero product has now been merchandised correctly

### Suggestion to Fix Caching

You could simply locate the Spring Bean that uses the caching strategy (likely to be the productSearchFacade), and reconfigure so that both the Backoffice and storefront no longer use caching. However caching is obviously a valuable tool, so I would advise at least leaving it on the storefront. This will mean that any changes made in the Backoffice will only reflect on the storefront after the cache element has expired, but at least you should be able to merchandise correctly via Commerce Search perspective.

### Other methods of Root Cause Analysis

If caching isn't the issue, I highly recommend that you change the logging level to DEBUG via the Hybris Admin Console for the two Classes (depending on whether you've chosen a legacy or default strategy)

**LegacyFacetSearchStrategy**

**DefaultFacetSearchStrategy**

This will enable the logging of the raw SOLR query for you. This gives you the raw data you need to be able to use the SOLR admin console at http://localhost:8983 and test out the different scenarios.